# After a few minutes WiFi stops working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kernel

Laptop configuration:
Model: Asus Tuf Gaming F15 FX506LI_FX506LI
version=1.0

I have booted with Ubuntu version 20.04 LTS unfortunately while installing the OS setup didn't ask me to connect with WiFi.

So I concluded that may be WiFi driver was not detected.

I Googled and it was suggested to upgrade the kernel to 5.12+. So I installed *Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer*, from where I installed the 5.12.8-051208 version.

Surprisingly my WiFi started working but, after few minutes it again stops working.

Then I have to reboot the system. Then only will the WiFi connect again.

After few trials I installed *Ubuntu 21.10 Imprish Indri* with kernel version 5.13 but, still the bug remains the same.

Please help me to get out of this bug or else I have to go back to Windows 10 because I'm unable to do anything from my new laptop.

I don't want to go back with Windows 10.